# Why is it 'a United States' in this sentence instead of 'the United States'?

Tags: articles

> Japan, Turkey, and Poland will each be facing a United States even
>   more confident than it was after the second fall of the Soviet Union.
>
> Source: The Next 100 Years by George Friedman

I used to see a definite article - "the" with "United States".
Even more peculiar it makes that fact that "States" is a plural noun and plural nouns don't take an "a" article.

Comment: United States isn't plural, it is a proper noun describing one country. It's like the Marshal Islands or the Netherlands - it may end in an 's' but it's sill just one country.

Comment: Related: [Their campaign mounts in fury as a free Europe crumbles](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75141/why-the-indefinite-article-in-their-campaign-mounts-in-fury-as-a-free-europe-cr)

Comment: Related: [a humanity that has come of age](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41609/a-humanity-that-has-come-of-age-why-theres-an-indefinite-article-before-a)

Comment: Just replace "United States" with the word _country_; that's how it's intended to be read – _Japan, Turkey, and Poland will each be facing a country even more confident than it was before._ It's an interesting construct, but you do see it from time to time.

Comment: OK. Let's assume that a United States is one of a set of versions of possible future [the] US. Will it be a mistake to use an article - "the" in this context ?

Comment: I think that's the point that J.R. is making: this is kind of a hypothetical construction.  We're not just talking about *any* United States, but the particular hypothetical US that is more confident.  So that's why it's correct to use *the*.

Comment: Related: the name of a political party in Russia is "[A Just Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Just_Russia)"

Comment: Futher George Friedman use the article - "the" in similar situation

Answer (score 5):

The source is correct, even though I could see how it would seem strange.

Think about it this way: When mentioning the U.S, the source is talking about a specific "version" of the country: A "version" that is more confident than your every-day United States.

> Japan, Turkey, and Poland will each be facing a **version of the** United States even more confident than it was...

It's not super common, but you will see that technique used every once in a while.

Also, as Colleen mentioned, "United States" is not plural because it is the name  of a single country.